# on click of tree node call action of controller spring

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring

I am new in spring development.On click on tree node i want to show different page for different node.
For tree i am using jqtree plugin.

On parent node click i want to render companyPage and on child node click want to show devicePage

```
$('#tree1').bind(
      'tree.select',
      function(event) {
        if (event.node) {
        // node was selected
        var node = event.node;
        selectedNode = node;
        //If node is parent ie company node

        if(node.id == 1){
           $.ajax({  
                type : "Get",   
                url : "company.html"});
           });
        }

        //Device NOde
        else{
           $.ajax({  
                type : "Get",   
                url : "device.html"});
           });
        }
      }
    }
    );
});
```

Controller for it is

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/company", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String company(Locale locale, Model model) {
      logger.info("Here in company action.", locale);
      return "companyPage";
}

 @RequestMapping(value = "/device", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String device(Locale locale, Model model) {
      logger.info("Here in device action.", locale);
      return "devicePage";
}
```

I am getting "Here in company action" on console on click on parent node but companyPage is not rendered.

Why??

I think i am using ajax in wrong way

Any solution to do so??

Spring config

```
<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing   infrastructure -->
   <context:component-scan base-package="........" />
   <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
   <mvc:annotation-driven />

   <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>
```

and other beans like messageSource,dataSource,SessionFactory and .......

Comment: Show your Spring configuration. What HTTP response do you get instead of the page that you expect?

Comment: @Alexey: i edit question..i am getting get company.html 200 ok in network tab..but page is not getting updated..same page before clicking tree node

Comment: There is no problem with your Spring code. Check your JavaScript.